# Bootstrap grid system same row but different height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been experimenting with bootstrap, and I have come across a problem.
I was trying to get a specific layout to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/7e5zh62y/1/

Problem is, I can't seem to get `header1` and `header2` at the same height.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZr2O.png) is what I wanted to achieve, so that when the screen gets smaller, the title and the list [stay grouped.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItWBI.png)

Is this possible to do? I've tried in several ways, but the closest I could get was something like:

```
    header1
    header2
    list1
    list2
```

which doesn't really work out.

Comment: can't understand what you're trying to achieve. draw it in paint then let us see.

Comment: I editted my question with a new image, anyways, here it is:
[imgur link](http://i.imgur.com/Upg24EI.png) I wanted `header1` and `header2` at the same height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second header has a left margin rule in the code. Get rid of that rule, and both headers line up.

[image]

As you can see in the image, you need to remove `margin-left: 50%` from `.col.sm-offset-6`.

Comment: Rather than trying to override Bootstrap styles, you should just remove the `.col.sm-offset-6` class altogether.

Comment: Oh, how dumb. I thought I had to include `col-sm-offset-6` so it would occupy the the space on the right. It worked with the removal of the offset class, and it works nicely when the window size gets smaller. Thanks!